# autohotkey ctrl+click = right click

Tags: autohotkey

What would be the code to turn a control+click to a right click?

I'm running windows 7 on a mac and would like to control click on the track pad rather than doing a two finger click.

Answer (score 9):

```
^LButton::RButton
```

Very simple! :D

Answer (score 6):

Try this. This works more similarly to the native right click than Juhzuri's solution -- the context menu comes up near the cursor; it works with controls that don't respect the Windows menu key (`AppsKey`); and it allows dragging.

```
^LButton::
  Send {RButton Down}
  Return

^LButton Up::
  Send {RButton Up}
  Return
```

Answer (score 2):

The following does it for me.

```
^LButton::AppsKey
```

I would suggest that you start with the following-

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm

Comment: This version doesn't work for me; if I control-click on the desktop, for example, the context menu comes up in the upper left of the screen. With @echristopherson's version, the context menu comes up where I click.